# Earth Engine dateslider for layers - app

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm pretty new to GEE, but i've have a map with many layers.
I want to make it possible to visualize the layers by a specific month/season over the years, when making an app.
Is this possible?
The script could proberly be made better than what I did, so ideas on how is also welcome
[Link for script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fmichelledh91%2Fm123%3ATest2%20(copy)50000m)

```
//Sweden2 STARTS HERE



//ROI is poin of intrest
//landsat8Sr is the USGS Landsat 8 Collection surface reflectance 

//Center the map on Roskilde (the location of POI with a zoom level of 13)
Map.centerObject(Sweden2, 7);

// Return the most cloud free Landsat 8 image covering the ROI from August 2018
  Landsatsweden2 = Landsatsweden2.filterDate("2015-05-01","2020-03-01")
                        .filterBounds(Sweden2);

// Sort on cloud coverage and return the least cloudy
var image = Landsatsweden2.sort('CLOUD_COVER_LAND').first();

//Find the 5 and 95 procentile values for each band within 5 km of the ROI and save as client-side variable (getInfo)

//Print image matadata to the console tab
print(image);

//Function to mask clouds and cloud shadows
function maskL8sr(image) {
  // Bits 3 and 5 are cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
  var cloudShadowBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(3).int();
  var cloudsBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(5).int();

  // Get the pixel QA band.
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));
  // Return the masked image, scaled to [0, 1].
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(1000);
}

// Mask clouds and cloud shadows on the image add comment to the nextrline to use the entier image
image = maskL8sr(image);

var pct = image.reduceRegion({
   reducer: ee.Reducer.percentile([2,98]),
   geometry: Sweden2.buffer(1000),
   scale: 30,
      maxPixels: 1038775950,
   }).getInfo();

var viz = {
  bands:['B4','B3','B2'],
  min:[pct.B4_p2,pct.B3_p2,pct.B2_p2],
  max:[pct.B4_p98,pct.B3_p98,pct.B2_p98],
};
// Display the true colour image
Map.addLayer(image,viz, "True colour");

//Function to calculate a NDVI image
function ndvi(image){
  var ndviImage = image.expression(
    {expression: "(NIR - RED) / (NIR +  RED)" ,
    map :{
      'NIR': image.select('B5'),
      'RED': image.select('B4')
    }
    });
    ndviImage = ndviImage.rename('NDVI');
  return ndviImage;
}

var NDVIImage = ndvi(image);
//Set colour pallet for ndvi image

var NDVIpct = NDVIImage.reduceRegion({
   reducer: ee.Reducer.minMax(),
   geometry: Sweden2.buffer(1000),
   scale: 30,
      maxPixels: 1038775950,
   }).getInfo();

print(NDVIpct)
var NDVIVisPAram = {min: NDVIpct.NDVI_min, max: NDVIpct.NDVI_max, palette: ["red","white", 'green']}  ;
Map.addLayer(NDVIImage,NDVIVisPAram, 'NDVI',true);


function exportImage(image,imageVisParam,name){
  Export.image.toDrive({
    image: image.visualize(imageVisParam),
    description: name,
    scale: 30,
    region: Sweden2
  });
}

// Call the export function Run the export from the Tasks tab
//exportImage(image,trueColourParam, "TrueColour");
exportImage(NDVIImage,NDVIVisPAram, 'NDVI_Aug');



// Use a DateSlider to create annual composites of this collection.
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1');
// Use the start of the collection and now to bound the slider.
var start = ee.Image(collection.first()).date().get('year').format();
var now = Date.now();
var end = ee.Date(now).format();

// Run this function on a change of the dateSlider.
var showMosaic = function(range) {
  var mosaic = ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleComposite({
    collection: collection.filterDate(range.start(), range.end())
  });
  // Asynchronously compute the name of the composite.  Display it.
  range.start().get('year').evaluate(function(name) {
    var visParams = {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], max: 100};
    var layer = ui.Map.Layer(mosaic, visParams, name + ' composite');
    Map.layers().set(0, layer);
  });
};

// Asynchronously compute the date range and show the slider.
var dateRange = ee.DateRange(start, end).evaluate(function(range) {
  var dateSlider = ui.DateSlider({
    start: range['dates'][0],
    end: range['dates'][1],
    value: null,
    period: 365,
    onChange: showMosaic
  });
  Map.add(dateSlider.setValue(now));
});
```

Comment: I suggest that you provide a **significantly** shorter script, focused only on your problem at hand.

Comment: @DanielWiell i've updated the script

Answer (score 0):

The below can hopefully give you a starting point. Sliders in EE are a bit limiting, so for cases like this using a select widget might make sense.

```
var region = ee.FeatureCollection('FAO/GAUL_SIMPLIFIED_500m/2015/level0')
  .filterMetadata('ADM0_NAME', 'equals', 'Sweden')
  .first()
  .geometry()

Map.centerObject(region)

var startDate = ee.Date('2013-05-01')
var endDate = ee.Date('2020-01-01')

var dateFormat = 'yyyy-MM-dd'
var numberOfMonths = endDate.difference(startDate, 'months')
ee.List.sequence(0, numberOfMonths.subtract(1))
  .map(function (monthOffset) {
    return startDate
      .advance(monthOffset, 'months')
      .format(dateFormat)
  })
  // UI widgets need client-side objects, 
  // but the list of months is server-side. 
  // evaluate() converts from server-side to client-side
  .evaluate(function (months) { 
    var selectWidget = ui.Select(months, '[Select month]')
    selectWidget.onChange(monthChanged)
    Map.add(selectWidget)
  })


function monthChanged(month, selectWidget) {
  var startDate = ee.Date.parse(dateFormat, month)
  var endDate = startDate.advance(1, 'months')
  var image = createMosaic(startDate, endDate)
  addLayer(image, month)
}

function addLayer(image, name) {
  var visParams = {bands: 'B4,B3,B2', min: 0, max: 3000, gamma: 1.8}
  var layer = ui.Map.Layer(image, visParams, name)
  Map.layers().set(0, layer)
}

function createMosaic(startDate, endDate) {
  return ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
    .filterBounds(region)  
    .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
    .map(function (image) {
      var qa = image.select('pixel_qa')
      var clear = bitwiseExtract(qa, 1)
      var water = bitwiseExtract(qa, 2)
      var snow = bitwiseExtract(qa, 4)
      return image.updateMask(
        clear.or(water).or(snow)
      )
    })
    .median()
    .clip(region)
}

function bitwiseExtract(value, fromBit, toBit) {
  if (toBit === undefined)
    toBit = fromBit
  var maskSize = ee.Number(1).add(toBit).subtract(fromBit)
  var mask = ee.Number(1).leftShift(maskSize).subtract(1)
  return value.rightShift(fromBit).bitwiseAnd(mask)
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/99c710072d77c4e5f41f2b527101a4a2